# 301 Redirection Without SEO Damage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, seo, http-status-code-301

I need to change some of my URL's without any SEO problem / damages. (i will delete all my old urls from google database)

For example,

old url: **www.site.com/search/term.html**

new url: **www.site.com/tag/term.html**

my htaccess file contains this line:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html index.php?do=search&keyword=$1
```

how must i change this? (i must be carefull about seo damages)

like this, **or???**

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html index.php?do=search&keyword=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html /tag/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this, you want the /tag/ URLs to do the search and redirect the /search/ URLs to them.

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*).html index.php?do=search&keyword=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html /tag/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you. but, will this transfer all SEO value of old link, to new one? (search to tag folder)

Comment: 301 redirects transfer most PageRank (read SEO value) but not all. They are the best you can do if you change URLs.